# Newtonsoft.Json: DeserializeObject(string value, Type type) returns JObject

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm using SignalR to receive a type name and Json, which for now I've relatively naively implemented by concatenating when with a pipe symbol on the server:

```
var ctx = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetConnectionContext<MyConnection>();
ctx.Connection.Broadcast(message.GetType().FullName + "|" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message));
```

On the client, I'm trying to deserialise back to the correct Type, but of course can't use any of the generic methods on `JsonConvert` so I came up with this:

```
var pipePos = eventMessageString.IndexOf("|", StringComparison.Ordinal);
var typeName = eventMessageString.Substring(0, pipePos);
var eventJson = eventMessageString.Substring(pipePos + 1);

var eventType = Type.GetType(typeName);
var evt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(eventJson, eventType);
```

The only trouble is that `evt` is a `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`, when really it should be an instance of the `eventType` type.

Is there a better way to do this, or at least a solution to get this working? I feel like I've missed something glaringly obvious - maybe I've been staring at it for too long?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the eventType non-null? When calling Type.GetType, you need the assembly-qualified name of the type.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I modified things to use the full assembly-qualified name and got `eventType` to be non-null. At this point I now have a problem in that the type is an interface, and Json.net doesn't seem to have proxying abilities so I'm going to have to change it a bit again. :(